# Can't store data using NSXML parser in a NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsxmlparser

I want to get data from webservice using NSXml Parser. I am able to receive the data(i can see that using NSLog. but i couldn't save the data in an array. this is my code.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
    didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if([elementName isEqual:@"entry"]) {
        NSLog(@"Found a title entry");
        getXMLFlag = YES;
    }

    if ([elementName isEqual:@"title"] && getXMLFlag) {

        NSLog(@"found title!");
        PTString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    }   
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{
    namazXmlArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"tab1",@"1tab1",nil];

    if ([elementName isEqual:@"title"] && getXMLFlag) {
        NSLog(@"ended title: %@",PTString);

        //      namazXmlArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"tab1",@"1tab1",nil];
        [namazXmlArray addObject:PTString];
        NSLog(@"I can't add this in array: %@",PTString);
        //Release and nil title String so that the next time characters are found and not within a title tag, they are ignored
        [PTString release];
        PTString = nil;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"entry"]) {
        NSLog(@"ended a namaz entry");
        getXMLFlag = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: is PTString a property/field? And what does the console say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be adding one array to another array. I'm not too sure why, and it's difficult to see what you are doing without your full code. This doesn't specifically answer your question but as your new to iPhone programming you might want to look at the class I have made available for XML parsing. You will then be able to parse the file using only a few lines of code. You can get it on [GitHub here](https://github.com/kieranmcgrady/KMXMLParser).

P.S Put all the code in code brackets when you post. It's easier to read :)

**UPDATE**
Once you have the data in the array you need to do the following:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [array count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      ....
         cell.textLabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey:@"title"];

}
```

Comment: Thanks kmcgrady for your help , Now i can store data in the array but i can't display this data in table view (but i can dispaly a static data in the table view), can you help me in this, but

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to get the data out of the array and display it in the table. Replace "title" with "summary" or "link" to get other data.